# Limit htaccess Blocking to just 1 Domain, when there are multiple?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess, I would like to block all public access to 1 domain except my ip address.

I know the code is this:

```
Order deny,allow

Deny from all

Allow from 203.25.45.2**
```

But I have 3 different sites on the same account that share the same htaccess file. So how can I apply the blocking code above, to JUST 1 of the websites on my shared server and not effect the others?

Such as http://blahblah.com ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In 2.2:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^203\.25\.45\.2
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

In 2.4:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} = 'example.com'>
    Require ip 203.25.45.2.
</If>
```

Comment: What do you mean in 2.2 vs 2.4? The type of Htaccess version? if thats the case, I have no idea, its just htaccess in my hostgator account

Comment: Those are releases of Apache HTTP Server.

Comment: I tried both of those codes, and changed it to my IP, neither worked. Any ideas?